# Error while trying to update values (cursor)

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to write a code which update my table base on table2.

Table1 contain column like: COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3...

Table2 contain column 2 column:
-First column contain name of the column from the table1 which should be update
-Second contain VALUE which should be set

So Table2 output:

```
columnname,value
----------------
COLUMN1 , 'sometext'
COLUMN2 , 'somethingelse'


set serveroutput on;
declare cursor doupdate
is
select columnname,value from TABLE2;
nazwa TABLE2.columnname%type;
wartosc TABLE2.value%type;
begin
open doupdate;
loop
fetch doupdate into nazwa,wartosc;
exit when doupdate%notfound;
update table1 set nazwa=wartosc;
end loop;
end;
```

While trying to run that code I got an error message which says:

PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NAZWA": niepoprawny identyfikator
ORA-06550: linia 12, kolumna 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

What I'm doing wrong? Same types of columns - Varchar2(200 bytes)
Edit. there is a problem only with NAME... Anyone know the solution?...

**EDIT2. I dit it and it works fine. I used dynamically SQL so it looks like: execute immediate 'update acc SET '||nazwa||'='||wartosc;   . Could anyone explain why that?:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `dynamic sql`, you have to execute it with `Execute immediate` command:

```
declare 
    cursor doupdate
    is
    select columnname,value from TABLE2;
    nazwa TABLE2.columnname%type;
    wartosc TABLE2.value%type;
    dyn_sql varchar2(500);
begin
    open doupdate;
    loop
        fetch doupdate into nazwa,wartosc;
        exit when doupdate%notfound;
        dyn_sql := 'update table1 set ' || nazwa || '=' ||wartosc;
        execute immediate dyn_sql
    end loop;
end;
```

**Edit**
A `for` loop and `using` clause will make things much simpler.

```
declare 
    dyn_sql varchar2(500);
begin
    for i in (select columnname,value from TABLE2) loop
        dyn_sql := 'update table1 set ' || i.columnname || ' = :a';
        execute immediate dyn_sql using i.value
    end loop;
end;
```

`bind` variable (`execute immediate/using`) will solve your problem of `smth, smth2` and `'smth, smth2'`

Comment: Hey Praveen, Yes, after few minutes I realised that i should use dynamic SQL. I have now other question. I got an error message when data in table2.value looks like : smth, smth2. Everything works fine when data looks : 'smth','smth2'  so there is inverted commas. Is there any way how to handle with that without changing data in table2?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a column named 'nazwa' in table1?

If you don't have, that will be the problem.

If you have, I guess that confuses the Oracle server, because it can't decide whether you think about that column or the variable named nazwa in your code. In that case you should choose another name for your variable.

Edit: maybe you're missing WHERE clause from you UPDATE.

Comment: hello, I edited my post. I did it by use dynamically SQL : )

Comment: now I see, I misunderstood what you wanted to achieve. sorry about that :)